# Проблемы с vk api (статистика группы)

Tags: python, python-3.x, вконтакте

В чуть суть проблемы: я авторизуюсь как сообщество(токен получил, проблем нет), возникает необходимость посмотреть список участников этого самого сообщества. Пробовал метод groups.getMembers, но он возвращал ошибку так как авторизирован от имени сообщества. Как лучше всего решить мою проблему?

> vk.exceptions.VkAPIError: 15. Access denied. request_params = {'method': 'groups.getMembers', 'oauth': '1', 'scope': 'groups', 'v': '5.62', 'group_id': 'bloodys_arts'}

Comment: Ошибка возникает, потому что это не Ваше сообщество. Обойти можно, использовав другой ключ (например, сервисный).

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка:

> Access denied. request_params = {'method': 'groups.getMembers', 'oauth': '1', 'scope': 'groups', 'v': '5.62', 'group_id': 'bloodys_arts'}

говорит, что нет прав просматривать сообщество. Используйте сервисный ключ.